# Get enum value by nested variable

Tags: swift

If I have an enum like this:

```
enum Types: String {
    case first = "First"
    case second = "Second"

    var id: Int {
        switch self {
        case .first: return 1
        case .second: return 2
        }
    }
}
```

Given an Int value of `2`, how would I get the Type, i.e. `second`?

Comment: Do the `1` and `2` have to stay `1` and `2`? E.g. do they mean something specific in the business domain, would it be okay to use `0` and `1` instead?

Comment: The name of an enum should be singular. e.g. `first` is a `Type`, not a `Types`. The name of a type is the name of one of its instances, not a collection of the instances.

Comment: Do the enum need to have have RawValue of String? Otherwise you can change it to Int and remove the ‘id’ comoutedProperty and just use ‘rawValue’

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Yes, 0 and 1 would be okay.

Comment: @Sajjon Yes, it needs a String

Comment: @user698515 I think you would have a nicer result by using an `Int` raw value, and providing a computed property which returns a `String`, which is like the opposite of how you have it now. Unless, you also need to be able to go both ways (`String` -> `Type`, `Type` -> `String`), in which case nevermind.

Comment: @user698515 how do you use the String? You could confirm to CustomStringConvertible. You can also do cool stuff with reflection using Mirror

Answer (score 2):

If you make the enum use the `CaseIterable` extension you could get a array of all values using `Types.allCases`.

So you could get the element by doing this:

```
Types.allCases[id - 1]
```